# req.params undefined for certain values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a router that for certain variables it will keep the params undefined. These specific variables are defined in my database as something but I'm not querying it so I don't know whats going on. For example:

```
    router.get('/:variable', function(req,res) {
      console.log(req.params.variable);
})
```

If I set put '85268' as the variable and it exists in my database, it will console log undefined. But '85267' isn't and it will console properly. But as you can see, I'm not even querying the database with this variable, yet it seems like it's linked somehow. I'm using Mongoose to model my schemas.

Edit: Here are some code files:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
var index = require('./routes/index');
var sites = require('./routes/sites');
var all = require('./routes/all');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var redirect = require('./routes/redirect');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/data2');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/new',sites);
app.use('/all',all);
app.get('/delete',function(req,res){

    var urlModel = require('./dbstuff/url.js');
    urlModel.remove({},function(err,info){
        if (err) throw err;
        else{
            res.send("All deleted");
        }
    });
})
app.use('/short/:id',redirect);


app.listen(port);
```

sites.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var url = require('url');
    var validator = require('validator');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var urls = require('../dbstuff/url');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    router.get('/*', function(req,res){
        var parsed = url.parse(req.path).path.slice(1);
        console.log(parsed);
        if(validator.isURL(parsed,{protocols:['http','https'],require_protocol:true})){

      urls.find({original: parsed},{_id:0, shortened: 1, original: 1},function(err,found){
            if(err) throw err;
            else{
                if(found.length == 0){
                    var newModel = new urls();
                    var newID = Math.floor(Math.random()*(99999))+1;
                    newModel.shortened = "https://urlshortener-gkt5015.c9users.io/short/"+newID;
                    newModel.original = parsed;
                    newModel.save(function(err,data){
                        if(err) throw err;
                        res.json({ original:data.original, shortened:data.shortened,});

                    })
                }
                else{
                    res.json(found[0]);

                }

            }

        });
    }
    else{
        res.send("False");
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

redirect.js

```
     var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url = require('url');

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("using the redirect path.....")
    var link = "https://" + req.hostname + req.originalUrl;
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(link);
    res.send(link);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Showing us more code would be greatly helpful.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Added**